# Unable to parse only the imageURL from JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
{
    "restaurants" : [
    {
        "name": "Hopdoddy Burger Bar",
        "backgroundImageURL": "http://sandbox.bottlerocketapps.com/BR_iOS_CodingExam_2015_Server/Images/hopdoddy.png",
        "category" : "Burgers",
            "contact": {
                "phone": "9723872337",
                "formattedPhone": "(972) 387-2337",
                "twitter": "hopdoddy"
            },
            "location": {
                "address": "5100 Belt Line Road, STE 502",
                "crossStreet": "Dallas North Tollway",
                "lat": 32.950787,
                "lng": -96.821118,
                "postalCode": "75254",
                "cc": "US",
                "city": "Addison",
                "state": "TX",
                "country": "United States",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "5100 Belt Line Road, STE 502 (Dallas North Tollway)",
                    "Addison, TX 75254",
                    "United States"
                ]
            }
    },
    {
        "name": "Pappadeaux Seafood Kitchen",
        "backgroundImageURL": "http://sandbox.bottlerocketapps.com/BR_iOS_CodingExam_2015_Server/Images/pappadeaux.png",
        "category": "Seafood",
            "contact": {
                "phone": "9724479616",
                "formattedPhone": "(972) 447-9616",
                "twitter": "pappadeaux"
            },
            "location": {
                "address": "18349 Dallas Pkwy",
                "crossStreet": "at Frankford Rd.",
                "lat": 32.99908456526653,
                "lng": -96.83018780592823,
                "postalCode": "75287",
                "cc": "US",
                "city": "Dallas",
                "state": "TX",
                "country": "United States",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "18349 Dallas Pkwy (at Frankford Rd.)",
                    "Dallas, TX 75287",
                    "United States"
                ]
            }
    },
{
        "name": "Buffalo Wild Wings",
        "backgroundImageURL": "http://sandbox.bottlerocketapps.com/BR_iOS_CodingExam_2015_Server/Images/buffalo_wild_wings.png",
        "category": "Wing Joint",
            "contact": {
                "phone": "9727019464",
                "formattedPhone": "(972) 701-9464",
                "twitter": "bwwings"
            },
            "location": {
                "address": "5000 Belt Line Rd Ste 100",
                "crossStreet": "at Quorum Dr",
                "lat": 32.95347617827522,
                "lng": -96.82554602622986,
                "postalCode": "75254-6752",
                "cc": "US",
                "city": "Dallas",
                "state": "TX",
                "country": "United States",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "5000 Belt Line Rd Ste 100 (at Quorum Dr)",
                    "Dallas, TX 75254-6752",
                    "United States"
                ]
            }
    }
    ]
}
```

This is the JSON I am trying to parse in iOS. I have created my Model objects with all the required parameters. I am able to parse and fetch all the data except for the backgroundImageURL. I get a NSUnknownKeyException. Can someone help me with this?

Below is the code used for creating the Model objects and adding them to an array.

```
 [self.restaurantsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Restaurant *restaurant = [[Restaurant alloc]init];
        restaurant.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
        restaurant.imageURL = [obj objectForKey:@"backgroundImageURL"];
        restaurant.category = [obj objectForKey:@"category"];
        restaurant.contact = [obj objectForKey:@"contact"];
        restaurant.location = [obj objectForKey:@"location"];
        [self.parsedRestaurantArray addObject:restaurant];

    }];
```

This is the Restaurant class:

```
@interface Restaurant : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, strong)Contact *contact;
@property (nonatomic, strong)Location *location;

@end
```

Here is the track trace:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundImageURL.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e631e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e0aadeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e631aa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010dd0a888 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 226
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010dc60997 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 280
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010dc60758 -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 437
    6   BottleRocketExercise                0x000000010cd8692a -[LunchesViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 282
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f2335ba -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:] + 483
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f235ae0 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4431
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f23a23b -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 247
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ea954a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001129a759a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000011299be70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000011299bcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112990475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001129bdc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001129be37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e55d367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e55d2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e552f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e552828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011245cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010e9de610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  BottleRocketExercise                0x000000010cd85f5f main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001106f192d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: show your full code and whole json

Comment: Please show full stack trace from this exception (NSUnknownKeyException)

Comment: we need more information. Show Your Restaurant Class and the full json

Comment: I have included more information.

Comment: I think i know what went wrong. can you show how you load the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that you have and array of restaurants and not just one restaurant. Your obj has not the keys because it has arrays of restaurants. You can only get the keys of each restaurant.